# Select a subgraph that contain specific leaves (igraph)

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph like this:

[An example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx87j.png)

I need to extract a part of the graph that just contains all of the paths from root (n2) to the red leaves. I found out that it is possible to extract the neighbours of a node, here n6 and n7, by the following command in R:

```
level = 2
subg1 <- graph.neighborhood(cGraph, level, "n6", mode=c('in'))
subg2 <- graph.neighborhood(cGraph, level, "n7", mode=c('in'))
```

and then combing subg1 and subg2.

but the problem is:
1. My condition is until reaching a node like n2 (root), not the level.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I also tried the following but I have 2 problems with them:

```
finalshortest = get.all.shortest.paths(finalSubg1, c("n2"), to = V(finalSubg1)[color=="red"],mode="out")
for (p in finalshortest$res) {
    finalsubgraph <- graph.union(induced.subgraph(finalSubg1,V(finalSubg1)[p]), finalsubgraph)
    finalsubgraph <- graph.union(subgraph.edges(finalSubg1,E(finalSubg1,path=p)), finalsubgraph)
}
plot(finalsubgraph)
```

1. get.all.shortest.paths doesn't give my all of the paths and it gives the shortest paths. For example, the graph has 2 paths from n2 to n6.
2. The final graph doesn't have the same attributes of the original graph.

Would you please help folks?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found it:

```
finalshortest = all_simple_paths(cGraph, from = c("n2"), to = V(cGraph)[color=="red"],mode="out")
V(cGraph)$keep <- "NO"
for (p in finalshortest) { V(cGraph)[p]$keep <- "YES" }
finalsubgraph<-induced.subgraph(cGraph, which(V(cGraph)$keep=="YES"))
```

Thanks again for your help Tamas

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that your problem is not specified to the fullest extent. First you say that you need to "extract a part of the graph, which just contains the red leaves". Obviously, this graph contains nodes n6 and n7 only (because only those are red). Since you then say that "nodes of n1, n3 and n5 should be removed", it seems like you actually want a graph that contains the *shortest path* between nodes n6 and n7, *ignoring* edge directions. If this is really what you want, then use the `get.shortest.path` function to find the shortest path between n6 and n7, then use `induced.subgraph` to extract the subgraph that contains only the nodes that lie on the shortest path between n6 and n7.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I corrected my sentences. Would you please check now ?